# biomarRT conversion of symbols

Tags: r, biomart

I wanted to use the code to convert mouse to human symbol, but I have problem with the mirror, I've tried to establish another one, but continue to have the same problem.

```r
musGenes <- c("Hmmr", "Tlx3", "Cpeb4")

# Basic function to convert mouse to human gene names
convertMouseGeneList <- function(x){
    require("biomaRt")
    human = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
    mouse = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
    genesV2 = getLDS(attributes = c("mgi_symbol"), filters = "mgi_symbol", values = x , mart = mouse, attributesL = c("hgnc_symbol"), martL = human, uniqueRows=T)
    humanx <- unique(genesV2[, 2])

    # Print the first 6 genes found to the screen
    print(head(humanx))
    return(humanx)
}
```

Comment: Show us the error message.

Answer (score 1):

My background in coding is more extensive in Python.  If you have Python skills, I can say for sure, use the Bioservices library:

```py
from bioservices import BioMart
```

Install Bioservices via pip:

```
pip install bioservices
```

You can also use the web-based tool on Ensembl called BioMart.  It does the same thing, just easier to use if you continue to have difficulties with Python or in your case, R.  I looked up the R package for BioMart, it is called: biomaRt

Here's the link for the Ensembl BioMart web-based tool if you need to use it and are in a crunch for time on your project:

https://useast.ensembl.org/info/data/biomart/how_to_use_biomart.html#introduction

I hope this helps! :)